# like query in php mongo db

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I am trying to implement MySQL like query in mongo db with PHP but I don't know how to do that.

```
select * from stud where name like "%abc%"
```

**php code:**

```
$regex = new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^(.*?(\abc\b)[^$]*)i$"); 
$result = $db->stud->find(array('name' => $regex));
```

**I also Tried this**

```
$result = $db->stud->find(( { name : { $regex: '*.abc.*'} } ));
```

Comment: tried, still no result found,$result = $db->stud->find(array('name' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('.*abc.*', 'i')));

Comment: wouldn't  `$db->stud->find(['$text' => ['$name' => "abc"]])` be the same/better, ie. full text searching.   https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-text-search-in-mongodb--cms-24835 , ps don't do `"$text"=>[` like me.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: Missing expected field "$search" in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#perform-a-like-match) to perform a LIKE match you don't need to use wildecards anywhere in pattern. For example to query `%abc%` you have to do this:

```
$result = $db->stud->find(array(
    'name' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex("abc")
));
```